# How to unpack/install a large number of windows application installers to find their actual executables?

Tags: windows, script, automation

I'm facing with a problem that i have a large dataset of Installers, and i need to install to gather their actuall executables, but there are many different installers in the dataset

I guess it is technically possible to write a AutoIT script that can install any application but it could get really really hard since there are many types of installers out there

So is there any solution to this? like an AutoIT script that can install any type of installer or an unpacker type of application that "unpacks" most installers? (Windows application installers)